# sqlite3 Insert or update

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I want to insert/update into one column at the time using sqlite3 while leaving the other columns unaffected. My current code just creates a new row instead of updating the existing one.

Edit: The important columns are `Strength, Dexterity, Speed, Defense` and are decided by `{data_type}`. Any other columns can be overwritten.

```
async function csvToSql(data_path, data_type) {
    const date = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY")
    let result = await csv().fromFile(data_path);

    db.serialize(function () {
        // Create table
        db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS daily(Date DATE, Name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, Profile TEXT, Strength Int, Speed Int, Dexterity Int, Defense Int)`, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

        //Populate
        let query = db.prepare(`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO daily (Date, Name, Profile, ${data_type} ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`);
        if (statType.includes(data_type)) {
            for (let i = 0, j = result.length; i < j; i++) {
                query.run(date, result[i].Player, result[i]['Player Profile'], result[i].Contribution, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);

                    }
                })
            }

        }
        query.finalize();
    });
}
```

Comment: If you want to only update the row then use SQL UPDATE syntax.

Comment: What if the row doesn't exist?

Comment: you need to provide unique identifier like ID or any other unique column if you would like to do it in one SQL statement.

Comment: the problem is that your DB doesn't know that you don't want duplicates if none of your columns is set as unique column. So basically DB will not evaluate new row as duplicate with any other already existing row.

Comment: OK, I set name as unique but now the other columns are set to null instead of keeping the other data.

Comment: On a side note, you *really* should be using a date string format like YYYY-MM-DD if you'll ever need to do any sorting or comparing of dates

Comment: Also, I suspect the [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) syntax added in 3.24 might be helpful for your issue.